# How to check if string contains more than one special character

Tags: bash, shell

I have this

```
if [[ ! $newstring == *['!'@#\$%^\&*()_+]* ]]
then
    echo Error - Does not contain One Special Character - $newstring
    i=$((i+1))
fi
```

Which checks if the string only has one single character from the bank, i want to check if it has more than one?

What would be the best way?

Comment: Stop writing your own password complexity checking and let people use passphrases.

Comment: I don't think that check tests for "one and only one"... The trailing `*` may contain any number of additional "special" characters... So it really only checks for "at least one"...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Either add a second class

```
if [[ "$newstring" != *['!'@#\$%^\&*\(\)_+]*['!'@#\$%^\&*\(\)_+]* ]]
```

or strip anything else out and check length

```
t="${newstring//[^!@#\$%^\&*()_+]}"
if [ ${#t} -lt 2 ]
```

Comment: Any reason you write `[[ ! x == y ]]` versus `[[ x != y ]]` ?

Answer (score 1):

We can use `tr` to solve it.

```
$ string='Hello-World_12@$@#*&%)(!@#@#'

$ number=$(( $(tr -d '[[:alnum:]]' <<< "$string"|wc -m) - 1 ))

$ echo "We have $number of special characters"
$ 16
```

This should be short and faster.

Answer (score 0):

```
#!/bin/bash

a='!*@%6789'; 
if [[ `echo $a | sed "s/\(.\)/\1\n/g"|grep -c "[[:punct:]]"` -gt 1 ]]; then echo shenzi; else echo koba; fi
```

Comment: This requires at least one sub-shell and two external commands.

Answer (score 0):

`grep` can be useful to provide the match

```
grep -oP "^[^'\!'@#\$%^\&*()_+]*['\!'@#\$%^\&*()_+][^'\!'@#\$%^\&*()_+]+$"
```

test

```
$ echo "#asdfasdf234" | grep -oP "^[^'\!'@#\$%^\&*()_+]*['\!'@#\$%^\&*()_+][^'\!'@#\$%^\&*()_+]+$"
```

will match the string as

```
#asdfasdf234

$ echo "#asdf#asdf234" | grep -oP "^[^'\!'@#\$%^\&*()_+]*['\!'@#\$%^\&*()_+][^'\!'@#\$%^\&*()_+]+$"
```

will not match the string

The `if` construct can be

```
echo $newstring| grep -oP "^[^'\!'@#\$%^\&*()_+]*['\!'@#\$%^\&*()_+][^'\!'@#\$%^\&*()_+]+$"
if [[ $? -eq 0 ]] > /dev/null
then
    echo Error - Does not contain One Special Character - $newstring
    i=$((i+1))
fi
```

Here the regex

```
^[^'\!'@#\$%^\&*()_+]*['\!'@#\$%^\&*()_+][^'\!'@#\$%^\&*()_+]+$
```

matches all strings with exact one occurence of the special character

Comment: could you have used [[:punct:]] ?

Comment: @ArunSangal yes i could have. just copied from OPs question.